# Can't connect to Firestore when Chrome is updating

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

This has happened on my localhost couple of times. I get `Error: Failed to get document because the client is offline.` error when Chrome is being updated. Authentication doesn't work either. I don't get the same error on other browsers. How can I prevent this issue?

My UI tech stack: React, Redux, Webpack